# Determine whether three sides form a valid triangle, and classify the triangle

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

This is a my first Python program, and whilst I am new to Python I would like to keep in good practice

Below is a short program to work out what type a triangle is and if it makes a valid triangle

I have tried to use as little documention for this as possible to try and get used to how things work in Python so I can only imagine the mistakes I have made. However please do mention anything that should have be done better

```
# Determin if triangle is Scalene. Isosceles or equilateral
# Also works out if lengths can make a triangle

from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 3
getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP

#Needs to be divided to re-set decimal place I think
a = Decimal(input("Length of side a = ")) / 1
b = Decimal(input("Length of side b = ")) / 1
c = Decimal(input("Length of side c = ")) / 1

if a != b and b != c and a != c:
    print("This is a a Scalene triangle")
    triangle_type = 'Scalene'
elif a == b and c == b:
    print("This is an Equilateral triangle")
    triangle_type = 'Equilateral'
else:
    print("This is an Isosceles triangle")
    triangle_type = 'Isosceles'

def is_valid_triangle(a, b, c,triangle_type):
    if triangle_type == 'Equilateral':
        return True #all same lengths will be a valid triangle
    elif triangle_type == 'Isosceles' or triangle_type == 'Scalene':
        if a == b:
            return a + b > c
        elif b == c:
            return b + c > a
        elif a == c:
            return a + c > b
        else: #This will be the scalene triangle
            return a + b > c
    else:
        return False #Message is unclear as could be lengths are negitive or correct int type not used

print('Is this a valid triangle?', is_valid_triangle(a,b,c,triangle_type))
```

Comment: _"so I can only imagine the mistakes I have made"_ Does it work for your test cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`__name__ == "__main__"` guard](//stackoverflow.com/q/419163), and move the logic into a function separate from the I/O:

```
def triangle_type(a, b, c):
    '''Return a string indicating the type of triangle
       (Equilateral, Isosceles, Scalene, Impossible)
    '''
    # implementation here...

def main():
    getcontext().prec = 3
    getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP

    #Needs to be divided to re-set decimal place I think
    a = Decimal(input("Length of side a = ")) / 1
    b = Decimal(input("Length of side b = ")) / 1
    c = Decimal(input("Length of side c = ")) / 1

    print(f"This is a {triangle_type(a, b, c)} triangle")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the implementation, we can save a lot of "or" tests by sorting the lengths before we start:

```
a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])

if a + b <= c:
    # N.B. automatically catches a < 0, since b <= c
    return 'Impossible'
if a != b != c:
    return 'Scalene'
elif a == c:
    return 'Equilateral'
else:
    return 'Isosceles'
```

---

## Modified code

```
def triangle_type(a, b, c):
    '''
    Return a string indicating the type of triangle
    (Equilateral, Isosceles, Scalene, Impossible)
    '''

    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])

    if a + b <= c:
        return 'Impossible'
    if a != b != c:
        return 'Scalene'
    if a == c:
        return 'Equilateral'
    return 'Isosceles'
    
def main():
    a = input("Length of side a: ")
    b = input("Length of side b: ")
    c = input("Length of side c: ")
    print(f"({a}, {b}, {c}) is a {triangle_type(a, b, c)} triangle")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

## Further improvement

Use the [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) module to write the tests:

```
def triangle_type(a, b, c):
    '''
    Return a string indicating the type of triangle
    (Equilateral, Isosceles, Scalene, Impossible)

    >>> triangle_type(1, 1, 2)
    'Impossible'
    >>> triangle_type(-1, -1, -1)
    'Impossible'
    >>> triangle_type(1, 1.0, 1)
    'Equilateral'
    >>> triangle_type(1, 2, 2)
    'Isosceles'
    >>> triangle_type(2, 3, 2)
    'Isosceles'
    >>> triangle_type(2, 3, 4)
    'Scalene'
    '''

    a, b, c = sorted([a, b, c])

    if a + b <= c:
        return 'Impossible'
    if a != b != c:
        return 'Scalene'
    if a == c:
        return 'Equilateral'
    return 'Isosceles'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have marked this one as accepted as it contains the more useful information, however both answers provide good points that I need to improve upon

Answer (score 2):

A bug (or poorly-specified behaviour):

If we enter an invalid triangle (e.g. `1, 2, 4`), the program reports that it's scalene, before telling us that it's not a valid triangle.  That's a contradiction - if it's not a triangle, it cannot be a scalene triangle!

I recommend performing the `is_valid_triangle()` test first, and only continuing to classify the triangle if the test is successful.

And don't forget that valid triangles have three *positive* sides - any negative values should fail the validity test.

Comment: little suggestion to test validity of triangle, valid triangles have three positive sides and sum of two side is greater than 3rd side

Comment: @prashant, the posted code already covers the second part of that test; I'm just drawing attention to the missing part.  I hope that's clear!

Comment: didn't went throuh the whole code, my mistake, thanks for commenting out